# No verbose output on startup after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown, startup, 15.04

When I was running Ubuntu 14.10, I was able to view the verbose output during startup and shutdown (which was very useful for me). But now that I have upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 I get the verbose output on shutdown, but I only get a purple screen, and then an Ubuntu logo with loading dots which can toggle to a black screen on startup.

In the past to achieve the verbose output on both startup and shutdown I did as follows:

1. Executed: `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. Changed the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"`
3. Executed: `sudo update-grub`
4. Rebooted

[Source](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21132026#21132026)

But as this only seems to work on shutdown, how do I get it to also show me the verbose output on startup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Log out of your graphical session and go to TTY1 whith <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Log in and edit the file `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

or if you like `vi`:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Remove the values for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Then update GRUB and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: That's no help to me.  I'm trying to install Ubuntu, and I can't figure out why it won't install because Ubuntu 16.04 defaults to quiet boot /while booting the install CD/.

Answer (score 2):

Change your line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`, update grub, and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have parameters other than "quiet splash" you can leave them in the line e.g.

> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"

change to:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="usbcore.autosuspend=-1"

The "usbcore.autosuspend=-1" allows me to place the laptop into suspend and hibernate modes - there is more to that than just these lines look here for more: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Don't forget to run:

> sudo update-grub

after you make the changes to your grub file.  Now you will not have a **splash screen** and you will see all the **verbose boot process lines** during boot.  The process is reversible if you get tired of looking at the boot processes just add

> quiet splash

back into the parameters of the same line.

Answer (score 0):

For me removing all parameters from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line causes stop system boot. I have encrypted disk and LVM. In this line I have some parameters that show kernel which partition is encrypted.
If you want to show all kernel messages during boot time edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file and find line

```
vt_handoff="1"
```

Change it to

```
vt_handoff="0"
```

and update grub config

```
sudo update-grub
```

You will have splash screen but if you press F2 button you will see kernel messages.